# Can you animate a beveled spiral curve into a tapered version with even thickness?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

Hey there I’m trying to get this beveled spiral curve into a tapered version (using the Simple Deform modifier) with even thickness.

[image]

but it’s turning out like this, ie flattened, is there anyway to have an even thickness if I’m animating from the untapered version to the tapered?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all I had to press was this button.

[image]